# Remove unwanted CSS from 1 stylesheet - inspecting all my website pages and not only one

Tags: css

I got a project to work on that includes a lot of unwanted CSS within a stylesheet.

I used a few tools like "[Audits](http://meeech.amihod.com/very-useful-find-unused-css-rules-with-google/)" (Chrome), "[CSS Usage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/)" (FireFox) and "[Uncss](https://github.com/giakki/uncss)" Nodejs npm package. 
They all output unused CSS for the current page that is refreshed or mentioned in CLI (uncss looks like this: `uncss https://example.com > style.css`)

I have thought of getting this by template - but the website I am working doesn't have any CMS and templates organized like Wordpress - it is built with Zend MVC Framework and there is no specific organized "templates".

What is the easiest way to clear unused CSS from **all** of my website in a more efficient way?

Comment: Have you tried the inbuilt feature of Google Chrome(Audits tab). It detects and helps you remove them easily ? Using so many tools seems like an overkill

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa as mentioned in my post - I used "Audits" and I am looking for a global tool and not for only one page on my website.

Comment: I tried this myself way back and came to the conclusion that "manually" was the only reliable way, but I hope you have better luck! :(

Comment: Best option I could suggest is to use the `grunt-uncss` task, [Check here](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss). In this task, you could pass all your HTML files and output a clean CSS file. Most of the tools out there will only show you the unused CSS, they cant all remove it for you. I guess you have already tried that but that is the best bet

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa the website is based on a Zend MVC Framework so there are no html file to pass :( - unless you know something I don't know about 'grunt-uncss'

Comment: Well then your situation is bad buddy. How can you programmatically detect whether your styles are being used or unused if your not allowing the HTML to be checked. I'm afraid manual is the only option you have in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a tool, https://www.bleachcss.com/, that detect unused CSS based on user actions.

Thanks to a little snippet of JavaScript, the tools detect use CSS selector when your user interact with the page and then send a report back to our server.

We then aggregate all the reports sent by all your users, and then we create pull request automatically to remove the unused CSS from the code.

By using real user actions, we are sure to support any kind of website, even pure JavaScript applications. Moreover, we are not slowing down your build system by adding headless browser runs or static analysis into it.

We are still in beta right now but I would love to learn more about your app, so please contact us if you are interested in giving it a spin!